# Cut scene reference, Family Guy's Chris is a reptile

Tags: family-guy

In one cut scene from *Family Guy*, Lois says "Chris doesn't take bad news well", then the cut scene occurs in which Lois announces to Chris that his grandfather has died and Chris turns into a reptile and spits black goo on her:

[image: Lois being scared by a reptilian-looking Chris]

What is the reference here? Is there a reptile that actually does this, or is it from a movie?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a reference to the [dilophosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilophosaurus) in Jurassic Park.

.
Although this dinosaur exists, it did not actually have a folding cowl (this idea was taken from the [frill-necked lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlamydosaurus)) and it is unknown whether it was venomous.